# How to implement radio buttons in a column along with other columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid

Working in telerik razor
my code is

```
 .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(itm => itm.id).Visible(false);
        c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("FN").Width(200);
        c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("LN").Width(200);
        c.Bound(itm => itm.location).Title("Loc").Width(200);
 })
```

I want to add a radio button as 1st column. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using server databind, you can do something like this.

```
.Columns(c =>
{
      c.Template(
      @<text>
          <input name="checkedRecords" type="radio" value="@item.id " title="checkedRecords" 
              @if (checkedRecords.Contains(item.id))
              {
                  <text>checked="checked"</text>
              }
          />
      </text>)
      .Title("").Width(36).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
      c.Bound(itm => itm.id).Visible(false);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("First Name").Width(200);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("Last Name").Width(200);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.location).Title("Location").Width(200);
 })
```

See the [example on Telerik's site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/checkboxesserverside).

For ajax binding, you would use ClientTemplate:

```
.Columns(c =>
{
      c.Bound(itm => itm.id)
       .ClientTemplate("<input type='radio' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= id #>' />")
       .Title("")
       .Width(36)
       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
      c.Bound(itm => itm.id).Visible(false);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("First Name").Width(200);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.name).Title("Last Name").Width(200);
      c.Bound(itm => itm.location).Title("Location").Width(200);
 })
```

[Telerik example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/checkboxesajax)